# Telerik test studio - How to get value (Which is given by user) from AutoComplete input box

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, telerik-test-studio

I am new to telerik test studio and automating a WPF application. I am facing a Challenge while fetching the value from auto-complete input box. Its a Address box which provides the auto-populated list based on characters provided by user.

for e.g - If i have typed "United" in autocomplete box then i want to fetch this value and also the suggesstion given by auto-complete list.

Please help as i am stuck in this situation.
Thanks in Advance guys..!

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No Chris.. I didn't found any solution yet..

Comment: HI Chris, I have found the solution for this. Just cast the Framework element in Autocomplete box and then use the Text property. It will return the given text